# Updating syntax for AppNavigator in react-native app using react-navigation v5

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation-v5

In my react-native app I am in the process of upgrading to react-navigation v5. For `AppNavigator`, which is passed into my main App.js file, the old code looks like this:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import LoadingScreen from '../screens/LoadingScreen';
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Loading: LoadingScreen
});

import MainDrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: MainDrawerNavigator,
  Auth: AuthStack
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Auth',
}));
```

The code gets used in App.js like so:

```
<Provider store={store}>
  <NavigationContainer ref={navigationRef}>
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="light-content" />}
      <AppNavigator ref={nav => { navigatorRef = nav }} /> // AppNavigator used here
    </View>
  </NavigationContainer>
</Provider>
```

From what I can tell, `createAppContainer` is no longer the way to handle this in react-navigation v5. I'm getting an error on this import specifically:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
```

... partly because the directory structure for the location of these kinds of imports has changed. But from what I can tell, `createAppContainer` is not existent now? In other words, it's not just an issue of it being located somewhere else now. Correct me if I'm wrong.

So my question is, what should this code look like in v5? Any insight would be appreciated. I'm referring to this `AppNavigator` code:

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator, createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen';
import LoadingScreen from '../screens/LoadingScreen';
const AuthStack = createStackNavigator({
  Login: LoginScreen,
  Loading: LoadingScreen
});

import MainDrawerNavigator from './DrawerNavigator';

export default createAppContainer(createSwitchNavigator({
  Main: MainDrawerNavigator,
  Auth: AuthStack
},
{
  initialRouteName: 'Auth',
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly first you need import NavigationContainer to contain all of your navigations

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
```

then after that create your StackNavigator like this

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen'
import LoadingScreen from '../screens/LoadingScreen'

function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name = "LoginScreen"
        component = {LoginScreen}
      />
    
      <Stack.Screen
        name = "LoadingScreen"
        component = {LoadingScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}
```

next, create the drawer navigator

```
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator()
```

finally the App function will looks like this

```
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native'
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack'
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()

import LoginScreen from '../screens/LoginScreen'
import LoadingScreen from '../screens/LoadingScreen'

function AuthStack() {
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator>
      <Stack.Screen
        name = "LoginScreen"
        component = {LoginScreen}
      />
    
      <Stack.Screen
        name = "LoadingScreen"
        component = {LoadingScreen}
      />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  )
}

const MainDrawer = createDrawerNavigator()

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MainDrawer.Navigator
        initialRouteName = "Auth"
      >
        <MainDrawer.Screen
          name = 'Auth'
          component = {AuthStack}
        />

        <MainDrawer.Screen
          name = 'YourDrawerScreen'
          component = {YourDrawerScreen}
        />
      </MainDrawer.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

I don't think there is Switch Navigator in React-Navigation v5

Comment: Not sure to understand, is the <MyNavigator.Screen /> syntax replacing the one where the screen was a parameter of the createStackNavigator() call ? 
Or is it just two different ways to create a screen (one with JSX and the other with JS) ? And if so one is now recommended instead of the other ?